# База данных в текстовом файле

Tags: java

Создаю простое приложение которое должно хранить данные пользователя в текстовом файле (один для всех пользователей), авторизация также должна проходить на основе этого файла. Подскажите пожалуйста как это правильно организовать? Может у кого есть пример такого решения.

Библиотеки использовать нельзя, также как и xml и json.

Comment: Реализуйте на коленке csv, в случае если не требуется использование экранируемых символов (т.е. приложение запрещает использование запятых и прочего) это тривиально

Comment: Та в java даже готовый Properties есть, который что то на вроде ini строит. Даже на коленке не надо ничего писать. https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-properties-file-examples/

Answer (score 0):

У меня есть пример, но не знаю может быть полезно для вас или нет !  И так!
Во первых создайте папку и внутри создайте `file` в формате текст это будет служить для хранилище данных, потом вам нужно клеить `lib` "я поставлю ссылку в конце".
Нужно создать папку с именем `model` и внутри создать класс который будет хранить переменные например `String name,String surname` и.т.д ...
Необходимо, чтобы этот класс был `implemets` на `Serializable` в этом классе нужно `ovveride-ить Getter Setter EqualsAndHashCode Constructor defaultConstructor` и в этом классе всё.
Потом, нужно создать папку с именем `util`, внутри создать класс с именем `SerializeUtil` и объявлять следующее:

```
public static final String USER-FILE-PATH = "И ЗДЕСТЬ ДАТЬ РЕЛАТИВ ПУТЬ В ЭТОМУ ФАЙЛУ ПРИМЕР -src\\mailService\\data\\users";
```

**И по этому пишем следующий, чтобы потом вызвать этот метод, чтобы кинуть `USER А` в файл**

```
public static void serializeUser(Map<String, User> userMap) throws IOException {
    ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(
            new FileOutputStream(USER_FILE_PATH));
    objectOutputStream.writeObject(userMap);
    objectOutputStream.close();
}
```

**И по этому коду пишем следующий**, который будет показывать всех `user` в консоль, потом этот метод можно вызвать когда хотите, увидеть всех `user`, но извините, я забыл логику, которую нужно было писать и вызывать этот метод:

```
public static Map<String, User> deserializeUser() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(
            new FileInputStream(USER_FILE_PATH));

    return (Map<String, User>) objectInputStream.readObject();
}
```

**Теперь создаем папку с именем** `storage` и внутри создаем класс `UserStorage` и внутри пишем следующий код, чтобы кинуть `USER А` в файл:

```
private Map<String, User> users = new HashMap<>();

public void add(User user) {
    users.put(user.getEmail(), user);
    try {
        SerializeUtil.serializeUser(users);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

И в главный класс, который я назвал `TEST`, нужно вызвать эти методы. Например:

Этот метод для регистрации:

```
 `private static void register() {
    System.out.println("Please input name,surname,email,password");
    String userDataStr = SCANNER.nextLine();
    String[] userData = userDataStr.split(",");
        User user = new User();
        user.setName(userData[0]);
        user.setSurname(userData[1]);
        user.setEmail(userData[2]);
        user.setPassword(userData[3]);
        USER_STORAGE.add(user);
        System.out.println("User was successfully added");
    }

}`
```

И когда регистрировали, все данные будут падать в файл.

Вот и `LIB` [про который я сказал вверху](https://cloud.mail.ru/home/Mail.Ru%20%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82/%D0%9D%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B0/)

Ну и скажите от куда у меня такой странный русский язык ....я не русский ))))

Comment: капслок конечно НАСТОРАЖИВАЕТ :)

Comment: Автор решил сделать текст нечитабельным и с ошибками, правка отменена, непонятно. Ну ладно, хозяин-барин, своего затраченного время  жалко...